# Character movement tied to keypress, increases animation speed with increased character speed

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, actionscript, keypress

I've come across a tough problem (at least for me) I can't figure out. I have a stick figure, and I want to make a simple running animation depending on if he is moving left or right, but also tie the animation speed to how fast in the x direction he is moving.

Below I included my code for how my character moves (all unncessary code from my game is removed). `xspeed` is what I want my animation speed somehow linked too. I could simply relate it to the absolute value of `xspeed` since it can be negative. Ideally, I'd like to have 2 animations, 1 for moving left and 1 for moving right. I thought about making both animations on the same timeline for my stickman1, then doing something like this.

```
if (xspeed > 0){stickman1.gotoAndPlay(2)}
if (xspeed < 0){stickman1.gotoAndPlay(5)}
```

assuming that my animation going to the right is 3 frames long, beginning on frame 2, ending on 4, and my animation going to the left is also 3 frames long, beginning on frame 5, ending on 7, and then on frame 4 and 7 just putting in some code that says `gotoAndPlay(correct frame to repeat)`. With that said though, I know it's always bad practice to do any coding on the timeline, so if possible I would like to stay away from that. Then it just gets worse. I have no idea how to speed up the animation =(. So that's where I am at, help concerning these problems is greatly appreciated, and the full code of my character movement is below! Thanks!

```
public var gameTimer:Timer;
public var stickman1:Stickman1;
public var leftBool:Boolean = false;
public var rightBool:Boolean = false;
public var accel:Number = 0.5;
public var maxspeed:Number = 8;
public var xspeed:Number = 0;

public function gameScreen():void
{
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, addSomeListeners, false, 0, true);
    stickman1 = new Stickman1();
    stickman1.x = 250;
    stickman1.y = 300;
    addChild(stickman1);
    gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick, false, 0, true);
    gameTimer = new Timer(25);
    gameTimer.start();
}

public function addSomeListeners(event:Event):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown, false, 0, true);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp, false, 0, true);
}

public function onTick(timerEvent.TimerEvent):void
{
    if(rightBool==true && xspeed<maxspeed){xspeed+=2}
    if(leftBool==true && xspeed>-maxspeed){xspeed-=2}
    if(xspeed>0){xspeed-=accel}
    if(xspeed<0){xspeed+=accel}

    stickman1.x+=xspeed;
    stickman1.y+=yspeed;
}

public function onKeyDown(keyboardEvent.KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){leftBool = true};
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){rightBool = true};
}

public function onKeyUp(keyboardEvent.KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){leftBool = false};
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){rightBool = false};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to manage your own animation system, but it's not as hard as it sounds :)

Something like this should work (assuming frame 0 is standing, and frame 1-n is running):

```
public var dir:int = 0; // direction you're going; -1 = left, 1 = right, 0 = not moving
public var speed:Number = 0.0; // the speed of your char
public var stickman:Stickman; // your stickman obj
public var prevTime:Number = 0.0; // used to calculate delta time in the update
public var currAnimTime:Number = 0.0; // our current animation time
public var currAnimFrame:int = 0; // our current animation frame

public function gameScreen():void
{
    // create our stickman
    this.stickman = new Stickman();
    this.stickman.gotoAndStop( 0 ); // stand frame
    …

    // add our listeners
    this.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this._onEnterFrame );
    this.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this._onKeyDown );
    this.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, this._onKeyUp );

    this.prevTime = getTimer();
}

private function _onEnterFrame( e:Event ):void
{
    // calculate delta time
    var currTime:int = getTimer();
    var dt:Number   = ( currTime - this.prevTime ) * 0.001; // dt is in seconds
    this.prevTime   = currTime;

    // check if we're slowing down
    if( this.dir == 0 )
    {
        this.speed *= 0.8;
        if( this.speed <= 0.01 ) // or whatever value you want
            this.speed = 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        // we're running
        this.speed += 20 * dt * this.dir; // or whatever speed increase you want
        if( this.speed > 20 )
            this.speed = 20; // max speed;
    }

    // if our speed is 0, just play the stand anim and return
    if( this.speed == 0 )
    {
        this.gotoAndStop( 0 );
        return;
    }

    // get our anim time - the seconds for a frame.
    // basically, if speed is 20, then our anim time will be
    // 1.0 (1 second) / 20.0 -> 0.05, or 0.05 seconds
    // per frame. We use seconds because dt and currAnimTime are
    // in seconds. NOTE: this is a linear transform of speed -> fps
    var animTime = 1.0 / this.speed;

    // update our current anim time
    this.currAnimTime += dt;
    while( this.currAnimTime > animTime )
    {
        // increase our current anim frame
        this.currAnimFrame++;
        if( this.currAnimFrame > this.totalFrames )
            this.currAnimFrame = 1; // frame 0 is our stand anim
    }

    // go to our new frame
    if( this.currAnimFrame != this.currFrame )
        this.gotoAndStop( this.currAnimFrame );

    // flip our scale based on if we're right or left
    this.scaleX = ( this.dir < 0 ) ? -1 : 1;
}

private function _onKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
{
    // move left or right
    if( e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT )
        this.dir = -1;
    else if( e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT )
        this.dir = 1;
}

private function _onKeyUp( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
{
    // stop
    if( e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT )
        this.dir = 0;
}
```

Basically you just change the time to show each frame for, and manually handle changing to the right frame. That way, your animation speeds up and slows down with the speed of your char.

Comment: edit: I added a `Math.abs()` around the `animFPS` calculation as `speed` can go below 0

Comment: wow this is awesome! The only other thing maybe you can look at again is the this.animFPS part. To me it looks like the faster we go, the slower the animFPS is going to be, since you have them inversely proportional. To me it looks like it should just be Math.abs(this.speed), but maybe I'm missing something? Also guessing there would have to be a proportionality constant somewhere there as well?

Comment: I wrote it out of my head, so there may be bugs in it :D
You can probably get rid of the `animFPS` variable; it's only there to calculate `animTime`, which is the amount of ms to spend on each frame. Basically, as `speed` goes up, `animTime` should be lower and lower, so something like `var animTime = 1000 / Math.abs( this.speed );`

Comment: "Also guessing there would have to be a proportionality constant somewhere there" - yeah, here it's pretty linear; how you calculate the final `animTime` depends on the effect you want. Check out easing equations or log functions (not my area of expertise, sorry)

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try and implement it today, it's all making sense to me at least =p